# Can parallelism be defined as a syntactic structure?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, parallelism

Can parallelism be defined as a syntactic structure? In my course, we study parallelism as an example of syntactic patterning. However, would it be ok to call it a syntactic *structure*?

Comment: No, not really. There are a number of types of repetitive construction that are due to syntax, like conjunction reduction; but in general things that are called "parallelism" in literature are just cases of using similar structures for successive parts of an exposition. This is just good sense, since people who understand the first part already have the parsing done for the successive parts, so it aids their comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to figure out what "parallelism" is, in general, but one place it is invoked is, indeed, a syntactic structure.  The structure is the conjunction of two or more phrases of the same syntactic category.  This comes up in three sorts of constructions:

A.  Conjunction reduction (so-called):

> [N' [N' [A blue] spots] and [N' [A red] spots] ]
>   [N' [A [A blue] and [A red] ] spots ]

where (in the example) you get to reduce a conjunction of two N's to a conjunction of two As.

B. Extraction:

> books which [S/NP [S/NP I like __] and [S/NP you like __] ]

where (in the example) you can conjoin two Ss with missing NP to get a single S with a missing NP, which is filled in at the left by "which".

C. RNR (Right Node Raising) constructions:

> [S/NP [S/NP I like __] and [S/NP you like __] ] books

which is like pattern B, except what is missing gets filled in at the right ("books" in the example) instead of at the left.

Comment: have a read here for more information about parallelism and deviation, which are both linked by the purpose of foregrounding http://www.lancaster.ac.uk/fass/projects/stylistics/topic3a/5dp&f.htm

Answer (score 0):

The context you provided is limiting to what I can write. What course are we talking about here?

I would not define parallelism as a syntactic *structure*. The syntax itself governs the structure of the writing, to which parallelism / deviation patterns within.